# PHP Multidimensional Array with Variables

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to make an array because I want it to rank it in order - but I have 3 variables I'd like to keep all together. Currently my Code is:

```
$WinningOrder = array("$ID1" => "$Score1", 
                      "$ID2" => "$Score2", 
                      "$ID3" => "$Score3",
                      "$ID4" => "$Score4", 
                      "$ID5" => "$Score5");
```

But I'd like to add another element to each which would be `$Total1-$Total5`

I thought of doing a multidimensional array but I'm unsure how to go about it when they're all variables.

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: You question is too messy in the explanation part. I don't see the overall goal.

Comment: You could look for this type of structure, if you see fit: [https://eval.in/922824](https://eval.in/922824). - Basically each variable will be a sub-array, keeping them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
$Score1 = 10;
$mainArray = array(
     array( "id"=> $ID1 , 
            "score" => $Score1 ,
            "total" => $Total1 
         ),
       array( "id"=> $ID2 , 
            "score" => $Score2 ,
            "total" => $Total2 
         )
    );
```

Access values like this

```
echo $mainArray[0]["score"]
```

this will output 10

You can also loop over the main array

```
foreach($mainArray as $item){
  print $item
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that your variables should not need quotes